# Add ng-Table ao Meanjs

Tags: yeoman, meanjs, ngtable

I'm trying to add a third module for use.
The module is the ng-table.

When I add the module in `applicationModuleVendorDependencies` returned one dependency injection error.

Am I not doing the right thing?

Someone has already implemented the ngTable using the yeoman generator MEANJS?

Comment: Adding a snippet of your code will help you get answers

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you post some sample code ?

Comment: http://embed.plnkr.co/ZX5bLGtVav9wTZ3FJJtx/preview

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the code would have been the best thing so that I can get to know what you exactly doing wrong or forgot to do, but I think either one or more of the following could be the cause

- you forgot to include it in your lib files in the config > env > development.js
- the library is not install yet
- or just a small typo somewhere

but I strongly suspect it would be the first point, as I have used it before, and worked just fine with meanJS

Comment: in my `config > env > development.js` cant find a way to add `ngTable`. Please check the gist: https://gist.github.com/arnold-parge/e7a4941099c939685a0a1ae02b2a7957